Using the XERO API, return voided invoices that have had a note added after voiding
Preamble
A voided invoice in Xero cannot be modified in anyway ... do correct me if I am wrong ...
Therefore I am assuming this means that the UpdatedDateUTC field will change for the very last time at the moment the invoice is marked as voided within Xero (either from within the frontend or via the API).
After this point in time the only change a user can make to a voided invoice is to add a history note.
Invoice Webhooks will send through a update for any invoice changes ... see https://developer.xero.com/community-forum-archive/discussion/118842649 ... however from my testing it seems not for voided invoices
My Question
Is there anyway to have the invoice webhook trigger when a invoice is voided and a note is added (or some other way)?
OR is there anyway to request all the voided invoices from Xero through the API that have had a history note added since a certain datetime?
